# Creating a treemap from a given entryset Java

Tags: java, file, tree, treemap

I have a file which contains a entryset formed from a treemap previously. I want to create the treemap of this entryset in my program. Can I do it with any method of Java or do I need to scan the whole file and add element one by one into the tree map?

Comment: To load a TreeMap, the only way is to put values one by one.

Comment: TreeMap is sorted, what is the object type for key here ? You might need a comparator.